# WinUI3 Application best way for app versioning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, version, winui-3

I'm developing a WinUI 3 application and my solution is composed of 18 project (1 is the WinUI 3 frontend). Most of them are class library and others are frontend one (like the Winui 3)

Each of this projects has own namespace and some of them is share common with others solution (in fact the namespase start with is CP.Common) and others are specifically of the single solution (in fact the namespace start with CP.ProjectName).

I see that when I create a App package of the Win UI application (with sideloading) Visual Studio create a version of the deployed file something like 1.0.10.0 and that's fine.

What I want is to know the best practice to manage projects version. I should want to retrieve this "1.0.10.0" version into the WinUI app or, better, the version of each projects involved just to have the right general vision on the project. Also it will be better if the versioning will be increment automatically by Visual Studio at each build but with some logic.

I find a tutorial that suggest to create a texttemplate file with all the logic and make a pre-build action that create the aseemblyinfo.cs file...I don't like it very much because it is involved in external tool and also it not solve the information of all the project version

Comment: You can try using Semantic Versioning

Answer (score 1):

For project version management, I use the Visual Studio Extension called "Automatic Version 3". After installation, it will just manipulate your `ProjectName.sln` file.

With this, you can automatically increment the project's version on each build. Or you can define custom Semantic Versioning for each of your projects.

Here is a link for the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.PrecisionInfinityAutomaticVersions3

I hope this helps!